# ng-if in angular2 doesnt work

Tags: c#, html, angularjs, typescript

My ng-if doesn't work. Please help

```
<div class="col-sm-12" ng-repeat="data in (result=(q.MyData | filter:q.Search))">
    <input type="text" value="{{q.id}}" class="form-control" readonly />
    <input type="text" ng-if="result.lenght==0" value="Data not found!" class="form-control" readonly />
</div>
```

Comment: Please check the docs first before asking a question https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html

Comment: do you have any errors? I noticed that you are misspelling `length` in your `result.lenght==0` condistion.

Comment: ng-if? ng-repeat? Are you talking about angularjs or angular2 because as far as I know, they don't exist anymore in angular2. Read about *ngFor and *ngIf instead ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Total guess, but you have an issue here:

```
ng-if="result.lenght==0"
```

Try correcting the spelling error:

```
ng-if="result.length==0"
```

Comment: Because `.lenght` is obviously not a valid function.

Answer (score 1):

In angular 2 ng-if doesnt exists, u sould use *ngIf and replace ng-repeat by *ngFor.

Use the angular2 doc to examples:
[ngIf](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgIf-directive.html)
[ngFor](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgFor-directive.html)